# Extend a Ruby Mechanize script to use a proxy

Tags: ruby, proxy, mechanize

I found a neat Ruby script to sum all purchases done on Amazon.de (no other stores like US) for a given year:
https://github.com/pwaldhauer/amazon-account-crawler

After installing Ruby and the necessary Ruby Gems Highline and Mechanize I'm able to run the script. But unfortunately I'm behind a proxy server so the script fails with a "Timeout" error.

I read a lot but didn't found out how to use a proxy server. I tried to "set" a HTTP_PROXY environment variable, but still get errors. I also used the following call:

```
agent.set_proxy('127.0.0.1', '3128')
```

But this didn't worked out as well. I have the feeling that the HTTP proxy worked but after the login Amazon uses HTTPS and this fails. 
Can someone tell me a simple way how to tell Mechanize to use a HTTP and HTTPS proxy server?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle to make the whole device you are using runs via ssh tunnle. Really easy to use. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known issue with mechanize https and proxies, you will need to use an older version (1.0.0) to get it to work. Also the port should be a number not a string.

Comment: How to install this old version? I tried with `gem install mechanize 1.0.0` but there is no such "gem" in the repository.

Comment: gem install mechanize -v=1.0.0

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked but now there is a different error:
`C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize 1.0.0/lib/mechanize/form.rb:136:in 'method_missing': undefined method 'id'
 for #<Mechanize::Form:0x12c51f0> (NoMethodError)
        from (eval):4:in 'block (2 levels) in forms_with'`

I don't know if this is still a connection problem or if I need to rewrite the script to use mechanize version 1.0.

Comment: try using name instead of id, or just forms[0] if it's the first one.

Comment: It worked for the login form, thanks. Unfortunately there is a dropdown box, which has no "name" field:

`select_form = orders_page.form_with(:id => 'order-dropdown-form')`
This is the HTML source from Amazon:
`<form id="order-dropdown-form" action="/gp/css/history/orders/view.html/ref=ohfilter_C" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="opt" value="ab">`

Comment: I will start a new thread for this, because it's a transition problem from Mechanize 2.1 to 1.0.

Comment: That's a good idea. In general if a form element doesn't have a name you don't need to worry about it because the value won't get sent.

Comment: "There is a known issue with mechanize https and proxies" - is there any way to know whether it is fixed in year 2015??